# UISegment Control Background Image User Change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want my app to have a settings that can change image when user press a segment in a UISegmented Control, however, I only know to show it in Nav Bar. How will I implement it in a way that there is a specific View for the settings, that when a user press a segment then when done is pressed it will revert to a new view with that background image.

Comment: use 2 or more buttons instead of segment :)

Comment: I want it to be a settings like. That the background image can be changeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lines of code.

```
 NSArray *ary=[sgmntControl subviews];
 NSInteger intCount=0;
 for (id seg in ary) 
  for (id imageview in [seg subviews]) 
 if ([imageview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
  {
   if(intCount==1)
    {
    [imageview setimage:[UIImage imagenamed:@""]; 

    }
    else 
    {
   [imageview setimage:[UIImage imagenamed:@""]; 

    }


   }
```

Comment: In this we just pass the imageview on segment control as a subview but using is kindclass method before somr days I saw in wwdc how to ise this method so I was try and this was be work for me.

Comment: can you pass it to another view? for example I implement this in SettingsViewController.m, how will I pass the the Value of the pressed Segment in the NewViewController?

Comment: For that use just pass the one global variable on segment click and use that variable in next view controller.

Comment: @bry are you new in in computer language.ok I will help you for that.

Comment: Oh its making a singleton, right? I don't know how to make one. Ive read other tutorials about NSUserdefaults

Comment: When you tap on segment control just pass that value in one global variable and call that variable or use that variable in next class.

Comment: ok In your .h class above the @interface add this line NSString *str;   and Pass this str value in your segment control tap in segment control method and use this string in next class.

Comment: I don't have the code yet, I only have the items in the IB. I don't know how to implement UISegmentControl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10948/discussion-between-bry-and-vishiphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image of segmented control like this
    UISegmentedControl *segment;

```
[segment setImage:UIImage  forSegmentAtIndex:segmentIndex];
```

or

```
[segment setBackgroundImage:UIImage  forState:ControlState barMetrics:UIBarMetrics];
```

**EDIT:**

You can try this for passing value to newViewController

```
- (IBAction)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
   newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
newViewController. selectedIndex =control.selectedSegmentIndex;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: newViewController animated:NO];    
}
```

before that you must set a property in newViewController

```
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController
{
NSInteger selectedIndex;
}

@property(nonatomic)NSInteger selectedIndex;

@end
```

and in implementation

```
@implementation NewViewController

@synthesize selectedIndex;
//your codes
@end
```

Comment: can you explain, Im kinda new in iOs.

Comment: I Will give an example for that
[segment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
segment is the segmented controll that you want to set the image

Comment: can you pass it to another view? for example I implement this in SettingsViewController.m, how will I pass the the Value of the pressed Segment in the NewViewController?

Comment: I did't understand your need. I just give code for setting image for uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: For example: I declare the segment to SettingViewController. When I click the segment in passes or saved it to another view,example named: NewViewController. like that.

Comment: can you apply it in this code: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Normal.png"];
    [imageToDisplay setImage:image];

Comment: i dont had any navigation controller, it seems to be having an error

Comment: what you want to pass to the newViewController

Comment: i want to display the image in the selected segment in a new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
 One of the solution is you can add imageView under UISegmented controller with same size , set alpha for UISegmented 0.01 and change the imageview image in UISegmented action method.like below

self.imageViewSegment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"segment%d.png",self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]];
//here your image names like segment0.png,segment1.png,segment2.png..etc
```

Comment: how will I pass it to another view?

Comment: For example: I declare the segment to SettingViewController. When I click the segment in passes or saved it to another view,example named: NewViewController. like that.